# Confusing indexing error while going line by line through some text

Tags: c#, error-handling, indexing

I'm reading in some text, line by line, and I'd like to tokenize the words and create 1-grams and 2-grams, but I think there's a problem with my indexing because I either get an index error or it'll say that the item I'm trying to modify in my dictionary doesn't exist, which is totally weird, since I wrote the code to first make the dictionary item and if it already exists, to increment a counter. 
Basically, my dictionaries are of the form **(n-gram string, frequency int)**

```
   System.IO.StreamReader lines = new System.IO.StreamReader("myfile");
    while (true)
    {
        string line = lines.ReadLine().ToLower();
        if (line == null) break;
        if (line.Trim().Length == 0) continue;
        string[] tokens = Regex.Split(line, "[^\\w']+");
        for (int i = 0; i < tokens.Count()-1; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                one_gram.Add(tokens[i], 1);
                two_gram.Add(tokens[i] + " " + tokens[i + 1], 1);
            }
            catch
            {
                one_gram[tokens[i]]++;
                two_gram[tokens[i] + " "+tokens[i + 1]]++;
            }

        }

    }
```

Can anyone look at my code and tell me where I went wrong? The problem seems to occur at the end of the for loop at the first line, but if I do

```
for(int i=0;i<tokens.Count()-3;i++)
```

then the error happens in the second line... but I'm not sure exactly what's causing it.

EDIT: As per suggestions, I tried using the ContainsKey method, but I still get an error near the end of the first line saying that I'm adding a Key that already exists, even though the if statements are supposed to catch that?!

```
for (int i = 0; i < tokens.Count()-1; i++)
{
    if (one_gram.ContainsKey(tokens[i]))
    {
        one_gram[tokens[i]]++;
    }
    if (two_gram.ContainsKey(tokens[i] + " " + tokens[i + 1]))
    {
        two_gram[tokens[i] + " " + tokens[i + 1]]++;
    }
    one_gram.Add(tokens[i], 1);
    two_gram.Add(tokens[i] + " " + tokens[i + 1], 1);
}
```

Comment: Wait I think I found the answer! The code in the Try clause was weird, it would cause an error at different times, I just removed the one-gram lines, but I am curious as to how I can keep them and have the code work without a hitch?

Comment: don't use exceptions for program flow.  You can check if the key exists by using the ContainsKey() method on the dictionary object.

Comment: @dbugger Thanks, I rewrote my code and posted it in the question. Do you know why I'm still having trouble?

Comment: You're always adding a token -- you need some else blocks

Comment: Thanks! I added else blocks and that did wonders, it's now much faster too!

Comment: Yes, exceptions are very expensive -- use them only when necessary.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use an `else` (or `break`):

```
for (int i = 0; i < tokens.Count() - 1; i++)
{
    // Save yourself typing errors by creating variables to hold 
    // the key values and then you can just use the variable name
    var oneGramKey = tokens[i];
    var twoGramKey = string.Format("{0} {1}", tokens[i], tokens[i + 1]);

    if (one_gram.ContainsKey(oneGramKey))
    {
        one_gram[oneGramKey]++;
    }
    else
    {
        one_gram.Add(oneGramKey, 1);
    }

    if (two_gram.ContainsKey(twoGramKey))
    {
        two_gram[twoGramKey]++;
    }
    else
    {
         two_gram.Add(twoGramKey, 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: I was on to this, but thanks for writing it up for others and adding the suggestion to reduce typing errors